# Nurb Interface Tool question - lost my way

Tags: modeling, nurbs-surface

When I add a Nurbs curve now I get the wrong icon and no hairy catapillar. Whaa, What did I do?  [image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In **Edit Mode** enable Normals Viewing on the side panel:

[image]

This works for all curves: Bézier and nurbs.

Comment: Except neither in Edit or Object mode I don't have the Curve Display  option on my side panel, in order to select  'Normals'

Comment: To make the side pannel visible Press N on the 3D viewport!

Comment: Yes I KNOW that much. It's not there Bro! See screen shot: http://postimg.org/image/mqkqgclyt/

Comment: Normals will not show in object mode. Press Tab to enter edit mode... please report if the option is not there...

Comment: Yes Sir...  I tried BOTH object and Edit -- it's just NOT there.

Comment: send your file over!

Comment: added blend file above

Comment: Any idea why my "Curves Display" is not showing? Does it show up when you open the blend file?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't look carefully. You are dealing with a *surface nurbs curve*, not a *nurbs curve*... I

Comment: Arrrgh. I'm so sorry. My stupidity Can you delete this whole questions then?